# How can I change the default error message code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, pdo

I want to change the error code SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'xx@yahoo.com' for key 'email' message into something like "error email already in use"

create.php

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if ($_POST) {

    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $contactnum = $_POST['contactnum'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $lang = $_POST['lang'];

    try {

        $stmt = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO tbluser(fname,lname,contactnum,email,pass,lang) VALUES(:ufname,:ulname,:ucontact,:uemail,:upass,:ulang)");
        $stmt->bindParam(":ufname", $fname);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ulname", $lname);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ucontact", $contactnum);
        $stmt->bindParam(":uemail", $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(":upass", $pass);
        $stmt->bindParam(":ulang", $lang);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Successfully Added";
        } else {
            echo "Query Problem";
        }

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

I tried to add something like this

```
if (mysql_errno() == 1062) {

    echo"error email already in use!";
}
```

But can't make it work. Thanks for your help, I'm still new in php. Can someone advise me how to use PDO?

addform.php

```
<style type="text/css">
    #dis{
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<div id="dis">
    <!-- here message will be displayed -->
</div>

<form method='post' id='emp-SaveForm' action="#">

    <table class='table table-bordered'>

        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='fname' class='form-control'  required /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='lname' class='form-control'  required></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Contact Number</td>
            <td><input type='number' name='contactnum' class='form-control'  required></td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td><input type='email' name='email' class='form-control' required /></td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name='pass' class='form-control'  required /></td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
            <td>Language</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='lang' class='form-control'  required /></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-save" id="btn-save">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Save this User
            </button>  
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to use a **SELECT** to check if the email exists and only do an **INSERT** if the email doesn't exist.

Comment: why not create a stored procedure instead of that.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_errno` is part of the deprecated mysql extension - you're using PDO, so you need to check the error with it too:

```
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Successfully Added";
} else {
    if ($stmt->errorCode() == 1062) {
        # Here ^
        echo "error email already in use!";
    } else {
        echo "some other problem...";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Errors can show up in event/error logs and cause unnecessary noise if you are ever trying to find a legit error, so if you can I would avoid relying on them. Instead try:

```
IF (SELECT 1 = 1 FROM users WHERE email=?) THEN
BEGIN
    SELECT 0 AS Result--signals already exists to the application
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO users(columns) VALUES(values);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS Result;
END;
END IF;
```

Or something along those lines.

Comment: What happens when two users sign up at once with the same email? Still need to handle error from the insert, concurrency means you can't trust the select to guard against constraint violations.

Comment: @casey Oh, certainly keep the constraint on the table. The issue is relying on it for your processes and having lots of unnecessary errors in your logs. If you get an error, treat it as an error, not as part of the normal flow